# How to disable Firefox Portable from automatically loading plugins

Tags: firefox, plugins, portable

Firefox Portable automatically loads plugins that exist on the host system. It probably doesn't make much of a difference, but I would like to only load plugins that I have added to my `FirefoxPortable\App\DefaultData\plugins` and `PortableApps\CommonFiles\` folder.

In `about:config`, I see that there is the `plugin.scan.plid.all` preference, but that does not remove all the plugins.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question just use the "Answer Your Question" button – you can even get reputation for it and accept the answer in a couple of days. This is how we mark posts as "solved" – putting it in the title unfortunately doesn't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Plugin_scanning) has documentation on plugin scanning and how to disable it.